# Polymer.js + OAuth2

Tags: ajax, oauth-2.0, polymer, web-component

Is there an example out there which describes how to implement an OAuth2 authentication in the frontend based on Polymer.js?

I just found some examples that describe the procedure for AJAX, which is also part of the Polymer element set. So how to go on ahead?

Comment: What OAuth2 provider are you trying to connect to? One of the big ones like Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc or some other one?

Comment: @Alan I have implemented my own OAuth2 provider based on Node.js (http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/) because we are building an on-premise solution.

Comment: Well then, if you already know how to do it using AJAX calls then you might as well use the [`iron-ajax`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) element since I don't think there's an element for what you need

Comment: Yes I assumed that iron-ajax can do the job - now I am figuring out how to do the authentication

Comment: Do you have sample javascript code of what you exactly want to do? It'd be easier to help you find an equivalent to that using `iron-ajax` that way

Comment: Hi @Alan, I have this one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440398/how-do-i-implement-secure-oauth2-consumption-in-javascript

Comment: That example uses AJAX not for getting the token but for actually accessing the api, is that what you want?

Comment: @Alan Okay, so that won't be all I need. I also have to obtain a token to authenticate each request I do

Answer (score 2):

I found a [git repo](https://github.com/mattcooper/oauth-authenticator) here which have demo. So you can take a look.

```
  <oauth-user></oauth-user>

  <polymer-element name="oauth-user">
    <template>
        <oauth-authenticator id="authenticator" client_id="282331888208-06mufq54k942624lv803nlm6kvlq76fr.apps.googleusercontent.com" scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" on-authenticated="{{authenticated}}"></oauth-authenticator>
        <core-ajax auto id="ajax" url="{{url}}" headers="{{headers}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></core-ajax>
        <p>{{greeting}}</p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            url: '',
            greeting: '...',

            authenticated: function(event){
              var token = event.detail.token;
              this.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token};
              this.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json";
            },

            ajaxResponse: function(event, response) {
              this.greeting = 'Hello ' + response.response.name + '!';
            }
        });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

You can see there're event handler so you can redirect user or update screen. There're also a url to get user info.